# No class def found for R.string of a library project

Tags: android

Basically, I have an android project which I am using as a library in another android project.  The problem is that when I run my normal android project, on run time when the following line is executed: -

```
editor.putString(res.getString(R.string.pref_key_srate), "" + AudioParameters.suggestSampleRate()); // line in library project
```

I get the crash

```
06-30 13:23:25.878: E/AndroidRuntime(3325): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.puredata.android.service.R$string
```

means that cannot find the R file when running as a library in another project. Now I dont want to replace all the R.string references with string literals but instead I want it to recognise R file of the library at run time.

Any idea how fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you setup the library following these steps: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html ?

Comment: Yes the library is setup like that but not working. I had to work it up by replacing the R.String with actual string litteral.